# use one hash to monitor a collection of revision hash changes?

Tags: git, hash, version-control, hash-function

excuse me for the vague title, let me explain:

I have a collection of git repos, and I need to come up with a "synthetic" hash which is generated by the revision hashes from these repos, so it can be used to differentiate which repo has new commits:

E.g. if I have two repos with latest hashes:

- repo A: `90d4b6`
- repo B: `fa880b`
- synthetic hash is `e0ea5a`

Next time repo A has new commits:

- repo A': `ac9561`
- repo B': `fa880b`
- synthetic hash' now becomes `12fc92`

Is there a way/hash function to construct the synthetic hash so I can tell from the change (from `e0ea5a` to `12fc92`) that this is caused by repo A changes?

I know the information about all repos's current revision hash, however I only know the "synthetic" hash from last time

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Use `no-ff` merge which will create a "side" graph for the merge. your merge will have 2 parents and using `git show <SHA-1>` you will be able to view the origin

[image]

[image]